# How to use more than one gridfilter type on ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am currently working with SQL Timestamp (date + time) values on my columns on the grid panel. To filter that correctly, I need a date and time menu on the column header. A combination of the 'date' and 'number' types would be enough.

In other words, I need a column header menu that has both the date and number types filter menu. How can I manage to apply two filter types to the column header menu? If that doesnt work directly, how to build a custom filter that combines the date and number types?

The number type:

[image]

The date type:
[image]

EDIT: With @abeyaz help i managed to build a custom column filter with number and date fields. Although, I was not able to find a way to make changes to the values on the fields apply to the store's remote filter. How should I go about setting up events to be called when the user presses enter on the number field, for example, to change the store filter array?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in datetime grid filter. However, you can implement it by yourself easily. First, check out date filter code. You must create a class `Ext.grid.filters.menu.DateTime` extending `Ext.grid.filters.menu.Base`, like in date class. What you can do is; instead of using `datefield` in `items`, you should use a field container that includes `datefield` and `timefield` together. Following example would give you an idea:

```
   menu: {
        items: {
            lt: {
                xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                label: 'Before',
                placeholder: 'Before...',
                operator: '<',
                weight: 10,
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield', 
                        flex: 1,
                        listeners: {
                            change: 'up.onInputChange'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'timefield', 
                        width: 80,
                        listeners: {
                            change: 'up.onInputChange'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

However, you must also override filtering methods to make it work correct because of different items. I created a fiddle for a [fully working example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2str)

Comment: That example is of great help, but when I try to implement that fieldcontainer on a Ext.grid.filters.filter.String, for example, I get a lot of errors due to the lack of event methods. Is there any way of overriding just the menu.items, and keep all event methods? It seems to me like a simple customization...

Comment: I didnt understand what you meant. It would be the best, if you would share a fiddle.

Comment: I edited the question with some of my advances. I was not able to make a fiddle work to show exactly my necessities, so I figured a picture of how I included it would be more helpful. I am currently using Ext 6.5 classic.

Comment: “up.onInputChange” is what you are searching for. See how i used it. You should use it in similar way for other fields. That triggers a refresh on store with new filter

Comment: “up.onInputChange” is looking for a method with that name on my controller. Is this the expected behavior? Should I code this method from scratch?

A method like that should flag the filter menu's checkbox and update the store filter.

Comment: No, that is just how extjs did in the date filter and i copied from there. That's a method in the filter field. Recheck my fiddle to see for example. You can trigger some other function from there according to your needs. However, in the fiddle the filter is applied while typing, so I dont know your case. Maybe, remote filter is different. Again, the best way to get help is always sharing a fiddle to simulate the same/similar behaviour. It doesnt have to be the same code.

Comment: Great! no problem